# C# .NET Core 3.1 Web API Post parameter is Null

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to make a post request from WPF to Web API using the following code but the request parameter is always null.

**Request Model**

```cs
public class Document
{
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
}


public class Request
{
   public string Uploader { get; set; }
   public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

**WPF Client**

```cs
var obj = new Request()
{
    Uploader = "John Doe",
    Documents = new List<Document>
    {
        new Document()
        {
            FileName ="I Love Coding.pdf",
            Buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\john.doe\Downloads\I Love Coding.pdf.pdf")
        }
    }
};

using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
    var encodedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var conent = new StringContent(encodedJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync("https://my-app.com/api/upload", conent);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

**Web API**

```cs
[Route("")]
public class AppController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocumentsAsync([FromBody] Request request)
    {
        // request is always null when app is running in production
        // https://my-app.com/api/upload

        //request is not null when running on https://localhost:8080/api/upload
    }
}
```

Please what am I missing in the above implementation?
The request parameter is not null on localhost but always null in production.

Comment: Where did you publish this app? What I mean is, that's a IIS or Azure server? Are you getting any error on it? Does your server accept post method?

Comment: Publish on IIS server and no error

Comment: Thanks for the information, please check  the solution and it would resolve your issue.

Comment: The _root problem_ here is that you can't really send binary data via JSON: JSON is a **textual** format - the most you can feasibly do is Base64-encode a few kilobytes (but no more, otherwise you'll run into general issues. The only _real_ way to make a HTTP request with binary content is to either send the binary content as the request body directly (so no JSON at all, and don't forget to set `Content-Type` correctly) - or with a `multipart/form-data` request which allows you to upload multiple binaries in a single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please what am I missing in the above implementation? The request
> parameter is not null on localhost but always null in production.

Well, not sure how are getting data on local server becuse, you are sending [MultipartFormData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa493937(v=exchg.140)) means your POCO object and file buffer. As you may know we can send json object in FromBody but not the files as json. Thus, I am not sure how it working in local and getting null data is logical in IIS Or Azure.

> what am I missing in the above implementation?

As explained above, for sending both POCO object and Files as byte or steam we need to use [FromForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources) and beside that, we need to bind our request object as [MultipartFormDataContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0) to resolve your null data on your UploadDocumentsAsync API action.

**Required Change For Solution:**

WPF:

In your WPF http request please update your request code snippet as following:

```
var obj = new Request()
            {
                Uploader = "John Doe",
                Documents = new List<Document>
                    {
                        new Document()
                        {
                            FileName ="I Love Coding.pdf",
                            Buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"YourFilePath")
                        }
                    }
            };


            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
              BaseAddress = new("https://YourServerURL")
            };

           
            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            
            formContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.Uploader), "Uploader");

            formContent.Add(new StringContent(obj.Documents[0].FileName), "Documents[0].FileName");
            formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(obj.Documents[0].Buffer)), "Documents[0].Buffer", obj.Documents[0].FileName);



            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/upload", formContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseFromAzureIIS = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

**Note:** Class in WPF side would remain same as before. No changes required.

Asp.net Core Web API:

In asp.net core web API side  you should use [FromForm]  instead of [FromBody]
So your controller Action would as following:

```
    [Route("")]
    public class AppController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocumentsAsync([FromForm] Request file)
        {
            if (file.Documents[0].Buffer == null)
            {
                return Ok("Null File");
            }
           
            return Ok("File Received");
        }
    }
```

**Note:** For remote debugging I have checked the logs and for double check I have used a simple conditionals whether `file.Documents[0].Buffer == null`. I have tested both in local, IIS and Azure and working accordingly.

Update POCO Class in API Project:

For buffer you have used `byte` for your WPF project but for Web API project update that to `IFormFile` instead of `byte`. It should be as following:

```
public class Document
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Buffer { get; set; }
    }


    public class Request
    {
        public string Uploader { get; set; }
        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent?view=net-7.0)